# jQuery 'Slides' not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidesjs

I am using the script at slidesjs.com (http://slidesjs.com/examples/simple/), trying to put it into my webpage. I decided to use a script and not just attempt to write it in jQuery myself as I could not get it to work, and I suspect the same problem is occurring here..whatever it may be. Here is the page source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>John Smith</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#sections').slides({
                preload: true,
                generateNextPrev: true
```

container: 'sections_container'
                });
            });
    
    
    
        
            
                
                    
                    Web Developer
                    John Smith

This text is purely to fill space until I add real content.

```
                </p>
                <p id="contact">If you'd like to contact me about anything, don't hesitate to email me at j.smith@example.com</p>
                <div id="social_media"><img src="images/social_media/facebook.png" /><img src="images/social_media/twitter.png" /><img src="images/social_media/flickr.png" /><img src="images/social_media/youtube.png" /></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3 class='heading'>Information</h3>
                <p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><strong>Name:</strong> John Smith</li>
                        <li><strong>Location:</strong> Sydney, Australia</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
                <br />
                <h3 class='heading'>Achievements & Experience</h3>
                <p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Worked at Google</li>
                        <li>Worked at McDonalds</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The CSS if anyone is interested.

```
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

a {
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}

body {
background: url('images/background.png');
font-size:12px;
font-family:arial;
color:#E5E5E5;
}

.sections_container {
width:768px;
display:none;
}

li {
margin-left:20px;
}

.sections_container div {
margin: 0 auto 4px auto;
width:768px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
padding:10px;
border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border:1px #7F7F7F solid;
box-shadow: inset 2px 2px #191919;
display:block;
}

.pagination {
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    /*
        Optional:
        Show the current slide in the pagination
    */
    .pagination .current a {
        color:red;
    }

.top {
margin: 15px auto 4px auto;
width:768px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
padding:10px;
border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border:1px #7F7F7F solid;
box-shadow: inset 2px 2px #191919;
}

.section {
margin: 0 auto 4px auto;
width:768px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
padding:10px;
border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border:1px #7F7F7F solid;
box-shadow: inset 2px 2px #191919;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {

}

#subtitle {
color:#919191;
text-align:right;
}

#title {
text-align:right;
}

#profile {
float:left;
height:52px;
width:52px;
}

#youtube_video {
float:right;
padding-left:10px;
}

#contact {
margin-top:8px;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:italic;
}

#social_media {
margin-top:40px;
text-align:center;
}

.heading {
text-align:center;
}

.demphasis {
color:#9E9E9E;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I can see a couple of wee issues.

Firstly, in your CSS you reference `.section_container`, whereas in the HTML it's `<div class="sections_container">` - note the 's' in the middle. Same for section/s.

Secondly, it looks like SlideJS defaults to "slides_container". Either rename your divs, or set the container name when you're initializing it:

```
 $('#sections').slides({
     preload: true,
     generateNextPrev: true,
     container: 'sections_container'
 });
```

I've created a little jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jCFeQ/ - it still has some issues, but is closer to working than when we started. Change those two things and see how you go.

Comment: I fixed the first CSS issue. Unfortunately it didn't solve the original problem but it fixed a problem I didn't catch due to display:none. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed the second part, still nothing is displaying but I'm going to go through and fix the js file so it aligns with my class names...thanks again. We'll see what happens.

Comment: Ok, I went through, the only reference was 'slides_container' which I changed to sections_container and then removed what you said above, however it is still 'not working'.

Comment: *Made some progress by removing the document.ready function wrapper that someone suggested but later deleted. I should be able to fix the css from here. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a typo in your CSS that refers to a missing HTML element:

```
.section_container div {
    ...
}
```

Instead of `.section_container`, your CSS should be `.sections_container` (note the plural) which matches your HTML:

```
<div class="sections_container">
    <div></div>
        ...
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Additionally, the **Slides jQuery Plugin** expects an HTML element with a class of `.slides_container` as the parent of the slides.

Since you've deviated from the default markup, you'll need to supply the plugin's  [container option](http://slidesjs.com/#container-name) in your jQuery function:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.sections_container').slides({
            preload: true,
            generateNextPrev: true,
            container: 'sections_container'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but given you've copied the code letter-for-letter from that example: Is the file you reference  in `<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>` actually there - do you have a js folder with that file inside it?

Also version 1.5.1 of jQuery is quite out-of-date. It shouldn't make any difference, but you might as well change that to 1.7.1

Comment: Yeah, slides.min.jquery.js is in a folder called js. I'll change it to the most recent version, however the example file used exactly the same version, so it should work regardless. Also added jQuery UI just in case. Nothing changed the result :(. Thanks anyway.